# SATA based Hard drives/SSDs models that are compatible with the PowerMac G5

Tags: ssd, hdd, sata, g5, power-mac

My understanding is that the PowerMac G5 series is *not* compatible with SATA III, so most SATA-based SSDs or HDDs will not work with a G5. I have a 2004-era G5 (PowerMac7,3) and I would like to add an additional SSD or even a HDD but I am unsure with specific models would work with the G5 given that almost all are SATA III-based - are there any recommended models that are known to work with G5s?

Comment: Have you checked vendor listings?

Comment: OWC shows HDD's that they claim will work with PowerMac G5's. Here is a link for [Power Mac G5 (2.00 GHz, Mid 2004)](https://eshop.macsales.com/upgrades/apple-power-mac-g5-2x2-0ghz-june-2004/internal-drives). I wonder why no SSD's are shown?

Comment: I'd also wonder why one of the drives in that list is SAS ;) idk about G5s but I've had no issues with SSDs in the Mac Pros.

Answer (score 1):

SATA I, II & III drives are all [forwards & backwards compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA#Backward_and_forward_compatibility), so any SATA drive should work.

Comment: Initially, I assumed you were correct. However, I choose a [SSD](https://www.pny.com/file%20library/company/support/product%20brochures/solid%20state%20drives/pny-ssd-cs900-sell-sheet.pdf) at random, which only shows backward compatibility with SATA II. According to [everymac](https://everymac.com/mac-ssd-storage-upgrade-guide/power-mac-g5-hard-drive-ssd-storage-upgrade-info.html), all Power Macintosh G5's use SATA I.

Comment: I can't test specifically to SATA I, but I've a houseful of SATA II Mac Pros, back to an 08, all of which now have SATA III drives in them, HD & SSD. I used to look out specifically for ones that said they were compatible, but manufacturers seem to have stopped bothering to say, so I just buy 'anything' these days, including over 4TB, where I need to change the sled mounts for them to fit.